# Application GetGSMStrength closed unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: android, signal-strength

I am a newbie to android..I have created the following application to return the Signal Strength

```
package com.example.GetGsmSignalStrength;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GetGsmSignalStrength extends Activity
{
   /* This variables need to be global, so we can used them onResume and onPause method to
      stop the listener */
   TelephonyManager        Tel;
   MyPhoneStateListener    MyListener;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /* Update the listener, and start it */
        MyListener   = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        Tel       = ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      Tel.listen(MyListener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    }

    /* Called when the application is minimized */
    @Override
   protected void onPause()
    {
      super.onPause();
      Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
   }

    /* Called when the application resumes */
   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
      Tel.listen(MyListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
   }

   /* —————————– */
    /* Start the PhoneState listener */
   /* —————————– */
    private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
      /* Get the Signal strength from the provider, each tiome there is an update */
      @Override
      public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
      {
         super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go to Firstdroid!!! GSM Cinr = "
            + String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

    };/* End of private Class */

}/* GetGsmSignalStrength */
```

but when I run it its showing the error mentioned in the title in a pop up box. I have made the necessary permission changes in androidmanifest.xml and thats all what I have done.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Why is the error showing up? When does it shows up in general?
Thanks

Comment: Actually, I am not able to find the error. I tried finding it but in vain.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the Android log file, the 'logcat', from which your problem should be traceable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "error" shows up every time an application causes a failure, an exception, which it was not designed to handle appropriately.

In Java, an exception is usually associated with the type of error that occurred, a message detailing the error, and a stack trace which allows to locate where exactly in the code the error occurred.

When an exception is not handled by the application the App is forced to close *and* the exception will be logged to the Android log file, the 'logcat', accessible via DDMS or from the shell via `adb logcat`.